# How to a add a vertical scroll bar to a JTextArea in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, jscrollbar

I have this Gui class:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -384241835772507459L;
JLabel playerInfo;
JTextField textField;
private final static String newline = "\n";
JTextArea feed;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
Player player;

public Gui() {
    super("Erik's RPG");        
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());        
    textField = new JTextField(30);     
    textField.addActionListener(this);      
    feed = new JTextArea(15, 30);
    feed.setEditable(false);    
}

public void setCurrentPlayer(Player currentPlayer) {
    player = currentPlayer;
    playerInfo = new JLabel("Health = " + currentPlayer.getHealth() + " | Mana = " + player.getMana());
    playerInfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(currentPlayer.getName()));
    add(playerInfo);
    add(feed);
    add(textField);
}
```

And it is annoying when a bunch of text is in the text field because it keeps making the window larger. I need to know how to make a scrollbar so the user doesn't have to keep resizing his JFrame. Also, how can I lock the dimensions of a JFrame so users can adjest the size?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `JTextArea` instance as the viewport view of a `JScrollPane` instance, as shown in [*How to Use Scroll Panes*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html). Add this scroll pane to the frame's content pane.

Comment: Can you tell me what the code would be? I'm a little confused.

Comment: It will be easier to suggest code if you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) in your question. More examples may be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#eg).

Comment: *"Can you tell me what the code would be?"*  Can you post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)?  (Even then, no guarantees are offered).

Comment: @ebalen which part of the tutorial chapter exactly confuses you?